# PyPSA-EUR SolveNetwork rule throwing error using cbc solver

Tags: pypsa

Followed **[basic steps](https://pypsa-eur.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html)** to setup PyPSA-Eur. Electricity only test was successful by executing

> snakemake -call results/test-elec/networks/elec_s_6_ec_lcopt_Co2L-24H.nc --configfile config/test/config.electricity.yaml

but when I execute

> snakemake -call solve_elec_networks

I get the following error

> AssertionError: In Line cluster underground, the values of attribute
> underground do not agree:

I am using default config and cbc for solving the network. Do I have to make any changes in config.yaml before executing solve_elec_networks rule?

EDIT:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/mnt/d/inc/pypsa_test/pypsa-eur/.snakemake/scripts/tmplkaoyzq0.cluster_network.py",
> line 515, in 
> clustering = clustering_for_n_clusters(   File "/mnt/d/inc/pypsa_test/pypsa-eur/.snakemake/scripts/tmplkaoyzq0.cluster_network.py",
> line 413, in clustering_for_n_clusters
> clustering = get_clustering_from_busmap(   File "/home/john/anaconda3/envs/pypsa-eur/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pypsa/clustering/spatial.py",
> line 535, in get_clustering_from_busmap
> lines, lines_t, linemap = aggregatelines(   File "/home/john/anaconda3/envs/pypsa-eur/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pypsa/clustering/spatial.py",
> line 436, in aggregatelines
> df = df.groupby(grouper, axis=0).agg(static_strategies)   File "/home/john/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py",
> line 1269, in aggregate
> result = op.agg()   File "/home/john/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py",
> line 163, in agg
> return self.agg_dict_like()   File "/home/john/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py",
> line 420, in agg_dict_like
> results = {   File "/home/john/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py",
> line 421, in 
> key: obj._gotitem(key, ndim=1).agg(how) for key, how in arg.items()   File
> "/home/john/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py",
> line 269, in aggregate
> return self._python_agg_general(func, *args, **kwargs)   File "/home/john/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py",
> line 288, in _python_agg_general
> result = self.grouper.agg_series(obj, f)   File "/home/john/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/ops.py",
> line 994, in agg_series
> result = self._aggregate_series_pure_python(obj, func)   File "/home/john/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/ops.py",
> line 1015, in _aggregate_series_pure_python
> res = func(group)   File "/home/john/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py",
> line 285, in 
> f = lambda x: func(x, *args, **kwargs)   File "/home/john/anaconda3/envs/pypsa-eur/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pypsa/clustering/spatial.py",
> line 136, in consense
> assert (x == v).all() or x.isnull().all(), ( AssertionError: In Line cluster underground, the values of attribute underground do not
> agree:

```
Line
1380     False
4002     False
5055     False
11429    False
9397     False
5795      True
5733     False
1376     False
Name: underground, dtype: bool
```

Comment: In principle it should work. Note that if you call `snakemake -call solve_elec_networks` without specifying `--configfile` you will use the `configfile: config/config.yaml` or if that file does not exist the file `config/config.default.yaml`. So it might be a configuration issue.

Can you post the stacktrace for the AssertionError?

Comment: @euronion thanks for your time. I have edited original question to include stacktrace. I have config/config.yaml in place with all the default values.

Comment: Thanks. This seems like a regression in the current upstream `master`. As a workaround you could set the `underground` attribute of line 5795 to `False` in the PyPSA `elec_s.nc`. A bug report on this in the GitHub repository would be welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Now fixed in PyPSA-Eur master via https://github.com/PyPSA/pypsa-eur/pull/714.